# Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file indicating the frequencies like 
"read 1 dick 1 john 1 book 1
read 1 different 1 a 1 different 1
"
i also have a dictionary defined for these words dict={'a':1,'book':2}

I would like to replace the words by their dictionary values. Could anyone let me know how is this done ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This question is really unclear. You want to replace the word `a` in the file with the number 1, and replace the word `book` in the file with the number 2?

Comment: no this is not a homework...some stuff i was doing as experiments

Answer (score 4):

```
text = # your text here
dictionary = # your dictionary here (don't call it dict!)
' '.join(str(dictionary.get(word, word)) for word in text.split(' '))
```

Comment: text.split() instead of text.split(' ') is simpler and will handle whitespace between words better.

Comment: @RajaSelvaraj, I did that first, but using `join(' ')` would turn any whitespaces to a single space, which may not be desireable

Comment: On the other hand, I thought it makes splitting a sentence into words more reliable, for instance if there are two spaces between some words.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

```
text = # your text here
for word in dictionary:
    text = text.replace(word, str(dictionary[word]))
```

**Edit**

For the problems regarding substrings, you can use regular expressions:

```
import re
text = # your text here
for word in dictionary:
    text = re.sub('^|\s' + word + '\s|$', str(dictionary[word]) + ' ', text)
```

Comment: This will create/copy a lot of strings

Comment: Use replace will cause the following problem: suppose we have text='boo book' dict={'boo':1} Using replace will lead to the result: '1k 1'

Comment: i tried this before...However the replace has a issue that it replaces it anywhere it finds a substring too...So for example my text is "read 1 dick 1 john 1 moby 1" but it gives :10 1 5 1 7 1 mo3 1". I tried converting the string to a list but did not find anything smart...

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = # your text here
dictionary = # your dictionary here (don't call it dict!)
re.sub("\\b.+?\\b", lambda x: str(dictionary.get(*[x.group()]*2)), text)
```

Comment: sorry it does....thanks for that...let me do some tests :) thanks for that gnibbler

Comment: by the way can we just make the entries are entered in a sorted manner ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `re.sub`, but supplying a [function as the replacement argument](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

frequencies = {'a': 1, 'book': 2}

input_string = "read 1 dick 1 john 1 book 1 read 1 different 1 a 1 different 1 "

def replace_if_found(m):
    word = m.group(1)
    return str(frequencies.get(word, word)) + m.group(2)

print re.sub(r'(\w+)( \d+)', replace_if_found, input_string)
```

... which gives you the output:

```
read 1 dick 1 john 1 2 1 read 1 different 1 1 1 different 1
```

The advantage there is that it's only replacing where you have one or more word characters followed by one or more digits.